# Correct array in url in Axios

Tags: axios, edamam-api

so I have started using Axios recently to create my first project. When I am trying to fetch data from the API, as default (i think) axios give me an URL like:

```
 /search?health[]=alcohol-free&health[]=celery-free&nutrient[]=calcium&nutrient[]=carbs
```

But the API (Edamam API) require:

```
/search?health=alcohol-free&health=celery-free&nutrients%5BCA%5D=100-&nutrients%5BFAT%5D=100
```

my parameters :

```
const params = {
    ...other,
    health:  ["alcohol-free", "celery-free"],
    nutrient: {
       CA: "100-200",
       FAT: "100" // under 100mg
    },
}
```

How can I correct my URL like that. I dont know where to fix the URL in axios. Thank you !

Comment: Do you use a library to parse the query string?  `qs` library: `import qs from 'qs'`
`axios(qs.stringify(params))`

Comment: okay, I'm gonna try that. Thanks !!!

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: @JoshSharkey, hey it works, you save my day :D

Comment: In that case. I will create an answer. Please mark it as the accepted answer and upvote if it is helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `qs` package to stringify your request before you call `axios`

```
const qs = require('qs')

const params = {
    ...other,
    health:  ["alcohol-free", "celery-free"],
    nutrient: {
       CA: "100-200",
       FAT: "100" // under 100mg
    },
}

axios(qs.stringify(params))
```